# convert String to int or default integer in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have some MySQL database tables where i store some column values as INT as mentioned in the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `nickname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `balance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

Sometimes **balance** field is coming as String from my data source. I want to make this case to default value 0 while storing in db. Is this possible? I just want to store only integers in DB. If in case any sting comes for that field i want store default value zero.

Can any one help me? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like more of a Java problem than a MySQL one.  Can you include the Java code you use to insert?

Comment: Side note: your `balance` column is an `INT` but the default value (`'0'`) is given as a string... While MySQL usually takes care of this kind of coercion, it's advisable to use correct data types instead.

Comment: mysql automatically cast strings it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, can you put the Java code? To be more precise.

Secondly, your default value is a string. Be careful about it.

You can put an exception code or just an if case that when the type of data is string, you add null (0); else push the data to your database. There are really a lot of ways to do it, but this holds more to the Java code and not the mysql itself. From you question I do not understand what precisely you want to implement and where is the error (problem) without your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of java code not mysql.

Do simple step, first which data you want to store in int format convert it into integer in java.

```
String balance="23";
int bal=0;
try {
    bal=Integer.parseInt(balance);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    bal=0;
}
```

Now pass bal variable into query.

Note:If value come in points like 23.89 than it also became 0.and if you want data save with point value than change balance in mysql as float.and convert string value to float in java.